# Apache2 default conflicting with other conf files

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu-16.04

Good day, I've setup apache2 on my Linux Ubuntu 16.04 server with multiple domains that direct to different `DocumentRoot` folders.

My problem is that when I disable the default configuration with `sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf` my configuration works fine and all the domains point to the correct folders.

The moment I enable the default configuration `sudo a2ensite 000-default.conf` then the default configuration "overwrites" some of the other `.conf` files and they point to where the `000-default.conf` defines as `DocumentRoot`.

Here are my two config files:

`address.com.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin address@mail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/betaFiles/
    ServerName subdomain.address.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} = subdomain.address.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin address@mail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/userweb/
    ServerName address.com
    ServerAlias www.address.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    Redirect /permanent https://www.address.com/
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =address.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.address.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

`000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

How can I enable all of them and still have it work the way I want it to???

Comment: please add the content of 000-default.conf, and the content of a .conf file that is overrided (just change IP and domain and other sensitive information of your .conf file)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.